# SSIS: Default Logging OnError don't work with RetainSameConnection

Tags: sql-server, logging, ssis, onerror

I'm using RetainSameConnection=true with my Connection Manager since I'm using transactions (BEGIN TRANSACTION, COMMIT or ROLLBACK in the end if success/failure).

I'm also using the default SQL Server Logging Provider and selected the OnError event (and others too).

The problem is I can't see the OnError event logged in the sysssislog table (the table exists and the default insertion SP is created) - I can see other type of events logged.

With the SQL profiler, I can check that the sp_ssis_addlogentry was executed:

> exec sp_executesql N'exec sp_ssis_addlogentry @P1, @P2, @P3, @P4, @P5,
>   @P6, @P7, @P8, @P9, @P10, @P11',N'@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2
>   nvarchar(4000),@P3 nvarchar(4000),@P4 nvarchar(4000),@P5
>   uniqueidentifier,@P6 uniqueidentifier,@P7 datetime2(7),@P8
>   datetime2(7),@P9 int,@P10 varbinary(8000),@P11
>   nvarchar(4000)',
>   N'OnError',N'EWOIU027013096',N'ad\oiu099',N'Empty
>   AF SINtemp','4CCEB32F-E884-483C-A02F-56D5C8438E44',
>   '15F585B3-AC6C-476F-8A2E-FC926438AC84','2012-07-12 14:46:15','2012-07-12 14:46:15',0,0x,
>   N'Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint ''CIRNAGF0p0_AF''. Cannot insert duplicate
>   key in object ''dbo.TIRNAGF0_AF''.'

But the OnError event isn't inserted.

When I change the RetainSameConnection property to false, it works, but then I can't rely on my Transactions SQL Tasks.

Note: I even tried to create another Connection Manager exclusively for Logging with RetainSameConnection=false, but it didn't worked.

I can log without any hiccup to a text file, but we need to log to a table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: But your profiler does show that N'OnError is getting inserted . Is it displaying for the other case ??

Comment: It's being rolled back, try using a separate Connection Manager for your logging

Comment: @praveen I can see the exec sp_executesql for every type of event independently of the RetainSameConnection value.

Comment: @msmucker0527 I've already tried a separate Connection Manager just for Logging (tried with the same Connection String and a separate one too) with no success; I also think that it's being rolled back, but why the other event types are being correctly inserted (PackageStart/End and OnPostExecute of Rollback and the Container)? Can I change my sp_ssis_addlogentry to open another transaction?

Comment: @AndreAlbuquerque I was able to successfully rollback transactions and keep the logs using separate connections.  The main connection had RetainSameConnection set to true, and the logging connection has it set to false, give it another try

Comment: @msmucker0527 I will give it another try, probably did something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue. Based on your description, I assume your package looks something like this. The SO_retain OLE Connection Manager points to the database where I'm working and have set the RetainConnection property to True.

[image: generic control flow]

I have added logging for events OnError and OnPre/PostExecute. I ran the package twice. Once using the SO_retain connection manager and once with SO_no_retain.

[image: sql logging]

After execution, I queried the log to see what had occurred. `SELECT L.id, L.event, L.source, L.executionid FROM dbo.sysdtslog90 L ORDER BY 1;` If you're using 2008/2008R2, modify the table to dbo.sysssislog.

My results were

```
1   PackageStart    so_Andre_LoggingTrxn    B2D17896-199F-4213-B800-E812CE95D45F
2   OnPreExecute    so_Andre_LoggingTrxn    B2D17896-199F-4213-B800-E812CE95D45F
3   OnPreExecute    Begin tran  B2D17896-199F-4213-B800-E812CE95D45F
13  OnPostExecute   Rollback    B2D17896-199F-4213-B800-E812CE95D45F
14  OnPostExecute   so_Andre_LoggingTrxn    B2D17896-199F-4213-B800-E812CE95D45F
15  PackageEnd  so_Andre_LoggingTrxn    B2D17896-199F-4213-B800-E812CE95D45F

16  PackageStart    so_Andre_LoggingTrxn    F6898ECA-46E7-4760-8885-898FADCBEFFD
17  OnPreExecute    so_Andre_LoggingTrxn    F6898ECA-46E7-4760-8885-898FADCBEFFD
18  OnPreExecute    Begin tran  F6898ECA-46E7-4760-8885-898FADCBEFFD
19  OnPostExecute   Begin tran  F6898ECA-46E7-4760-8885-898FADCBEFFD
20  OnPreExecute    Sequence Container  F6898ECA-46E7-4760-8885-898FADCBEFFD
21  OnPreExecute    Divide by zero  F6898ECA-46E7-4760-8885-898FADCBEFFD
22  OnError Divide by zero  F6898ECA-46E7-4760-8885-898FADCBEFFD
23  OnError Sequence Container  F6898ECA-46E7-4760-8885-898FADCBEFFD
24  OnError so_Andre_LoggingTrxn    F6898ECA-46E7-4760-8885-898FADCBEFFD
25  OnPostExecute   Divide by zero  F6898ECA-46E7-4760-8885-898FADCBEFFD
26  OnPostExecute   Sequence Container  F6898ECA-46E7-4760-8885-898FADCBEFFD
27  OnPreExecute    Rollback    F6898ECA-46E7-4760-8885-898FADCBEFFD
28  OnPostExecute   Rollback    F6898ECA-46E7-4760-8885-898FADCBEFFD
29  OnPostExecute   so_Andre_LoggingTrxn    F6898ECA-46E7-4760-8885-898FADCBEFFD
30  PackageEnd  so_Andre_LoggingTrxn    F6898ECA-46E7-4760-8885-898FADCBEFFD
```

As you can see, things are happening as one would expect in a transaction. In the first execution, the package begins firing events which are logged (PackageStart, OnPreExecute). The OnPreExecute for source "Begin tran" is the last thing we see until the OnPostExecute of "Rollback" fires. However, there is a gap in the IDs. That gap are all the inserts that occurred under the transaction. That transaction is rolled back so all of that work is undone and the only indicator is the consumed identity values.

When I change logging to use SO_no_retain for the connection manager, I see the OnError events being logged.

### edits

You are seeing the first set of entries in your log but the desire is to see the second.

Understanding why this is so is fundamental to [how transactions work](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/introduction-to-transactions). A transaction packages up statements of work into a single block of stuff that's *all* going to work or it's *all* going to fail. In your transaction, the package is issuing sp_ssis_addlogentry commands. There's no way inside the current transaction to say "make these statements more durable than the rest" or "persist these outside the current transaction." All or none, that's the only option within the context of a transaction.

Given that, your options are either create a second connection manager dedicated to logging as I has shown with the SO_no_retain CM or write your own error logging system. I really, really would advocate the former as it's native behaviour. Otherwise, you're going to spend lots of time

### A third option

This one struck me that perhaps you weren't aware of it. You don't need to the begin tran /commit/rollback pattern. SSIS can do that out of the box for you. Depending on where the packages run, it will require the MSDTC (MS distributed transaction coordinator) to be running but in short, you tell the package that you'd like to have these components enlist in a transaction and voila, magic happens and you don't have to manage it. Every task in SSIS has a property for TransactionOption. By default, that is set to Supported.

[TransactionOption settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137690.aspx)

- **Supported** If a transaction exists, the task will enlist in it. It will not start a transaction.
- **Required** This will start a transaction. If one already exists, then it will enlist in that transaction
- **NotRequired** This will not start a transaction, nor will it enlist in an ongoing transaction. You *can* deadlock yourself by having required and not required objects attempting to manipulate the same resources so watch what you're doing.

Given the above package, what I would do is

1. remove the Execute SQL Tasks that coordinate transaction,
2. leave the RetainSameConnection property as False
3. At the control flow level (or Sequence Container) I would set the TransactionOption to Required

Done, that's it. When the package runs, the "work" is rolled back but the logging, including errors, will be there. Quite honestly, most every package I write looks something like that. I've never had reason to attempt to control my own transactions as I, perhaps foolishly, trust the transaction coordinator to handle all of that. In 7 years of working with SSIS though, I haven't had troubles with the MSDTC not handling it.

Comment: That's exactly what's happening (my SSIS package looks exactly like yours). We need the OnError logs, even if they get rolled back. Can I use another transaction inside the sp_ssis_addlogentry to accomplish this?

Comment: I remember reading about that but thought that it was another dependency to rely on (MSDTC). Is MSDTC executed by default? When I'm running locally, I have to start the service manually.